# False Position method-root in the interval (x0,x1)

Tags: calculus

can anyone help me on this?

I am studying the False Position method.

I understand the method and how it uses a secant line that connects the interval that we are analysing example [x0,x1] to find the approximated root of the original function.

However I don not understand how can I show that the approximated root  is guaranteed to be in the interval (x0,x1) mathematically.

Is it enough to show it using a visual example such as graphs? Or is there any  mathematical way to show this?

Thank you

Comment: for your question see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x_0)$ and $f(x_1)$ are non-zero with opposite sign. This shows you that there is a root of the secant line inside the interval $[x_0,x_1]$ and it can not be at the end points.

Alternatively, convince yourself that under the above assumptions
$$
x_2 = \frac{|f(x_1)|·x_0+|f(x_0)|·x_1}{|f(x_1)|+|f(x_0)|}
$$
which is a convex combination of $x_0$ and $x_1$, thus inside the segment $[x_0,x_1]$.